# Getting top n records for each group in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I need to group the data from a neo4j database and then to filter out everything except the top `n` records of every group.

Example:

I have two node types : Order and Article. Between them there is an "ADDED" relationship. "ADDED" relationship has a timestamp property. What I want to know (for every article) is how many times it was among the first two articles added to an order. What I tried is the following approach:

1. get all the Order-[ADDED]-Article
2. sort the result from step 1 by order id as first sorting key and then by timestamp of ADDED relationship as second sorting key;
3. for every subgroup from step 2 representing one order, keep only the top 2 rows;
4. Count distinct article ids in the output of step 3;

My problem is that I got stuck at step 3. Is it possible to get top 2 rows for every subgroup representing an order?

Thanks,

Tiberiu

Comment: Could you please show us your model?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907134/return-top-n-results-for-each-query-in-neo4j ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
MATCH (o:Order)-[r:ADDED]->(a:Article)
WITH o, r, a
ORDER BY o.oid, r.t
WITH o, COLLECT(a)[..2] AS topArticlesByOrder UNWIND topArticlesByOrder AS a
RETURN a.aid AS articleId, COUNT(*) AS count
```

Results look like

```
articleId    count
   8           6
   2           2
   4           5
   7           2
   3           3
   6           5
   0           7
```

on this [sample graph](http://console.neo4j.org/r/bbih4b) created with

```
FOREACH(opar IN RANGE(1,15) |
    MERGE (o:Order {oid:opar})
    FOREACH(apar IN RANGE(1,5) |
        MERGE (a:Article {aid:TOINT(RAND()*10)})
        CREATE o-[:ADDED {t:timestamp() - TOINT(RAND()*1000)}]->a
    )
)
```

Comment: Good answer. I wouldn't collect `r`, though. You can avoid having to deal with `endnode` by just collecting `a`:

`MATCH (o:Order)-[r:ADDED]->(a:Article)
WITH o, r, a
ORDER BY o.oid, r.t
WITH o, COLLECT(a)[..2] AS top_articles UNWIND top_articles AS articles
RETURN articles.aid, COUNT(*) AS count
ORDER BY count DESC;`

Comment: @NicoleWhite You're right, thanks! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Good one Jonatan, I was just a bit confused by the _very short_ identifier and property-names :) And depending on the numbers of articles it might be better to do `WITH a, count(*) as count RETURN a.id, count` to reduce the # of property accesses.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Yeah, the identifier/property names are a bit terse :) I'd can change that, and you're right of course about postponing property access, but for some reason your suggestion actually gives different results: http://console.neo4j.org/r/gjfmjf. I'll have to pause and think later about why. Thanks for the comment, it's a rare thing to get feedback from two experts like this!

Answer (score 2):

Use `LIMIT` combined with `ORDER BY` to get the top N of anything.   For example, the top 5 scores would be:

```
MATCH (node:MyScoreNode) 
RETURN node
ORDER BY node.score DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

The `ORDER BY` part ensures the highest scores show up first.  The `LIMIT` gives you only the first 5, which since they're sorted, are always the highest.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's not exactly what I want. Probably my question was not clear enough. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve your desired results and failed.

So, my guess - this one is impossible with *pure* cypher.

What is the problem? Cypher is considering everything as a paths. And actually is doing traverse.
Trying to group results and then execute filter on each group means that cypher should somehow branch it traversing at some points. But Cypher executed filter on all results, because they are considered as collection of different paths.

My suggestion - create several queries, that achieves desired functionality, and implement some client-side logic.