# Neo4j - Returning multiple sets of rows for each node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having 1000 employee nodes and they belong to 7 divisions.I am trying to get the top 10 messages sent by each employee in finance division to other employees in descending order. I also want the division of employee to whom he has sent the message. I am using the following query according to the answers given in these two questions:
[return top n results for each query in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907134/return-top-n-results-for-each-query-in-neo4j?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and [Getting top n records for each group in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951651/getting-top-n-records-for-each-group-in-neo4j?noredirect=1&lq=1),
but the result I am getting is top 10 messages sent by each employee to other employees of each division (a total of 70 messages for each employee). I want the results including all divisions collectively and not 10 results for each division.

The query I used is:

```
MATCH(e:Employee{div:'finance'}),(b:Employee)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[r:Message]->(b)
WITH e.name as em, b.division_name as bm,coalesce(r.NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES,0) 
as msg 
ORDER BY msg DESC 
WITH collect(msg) AS bts, em, bm
UNWIND bts[0..10] AS r
RETURN em, bm, r
```

What changes should I make to this query? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can share with us a Cypher script to build a sample data set and the expected result?

Comment: Each employee node has 2 properties his name and division. The interaction between them is given by a relationship "Message", which has a property "NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES". here is a link to the type of output i am trying to get: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AoPLdWnC_z5RjuUiFQ9tdmoDa2BbfQ

Comment: Dear Bruno, the graph is built from csv files and I am not exactly sure how to build the sample for that. I hope that the output I am trying to get make sense to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ram, I believe a good choice to do it is using the [APOC Procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) `apoc.cypher.run`. With this procedure you will able to run a "sub query" for each employee that works in the finance division. Please, install APOC Procedures and try it:

```
MATCH(e:Employee{div:'finance'})
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
    WITH {e} AS e
    OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(b:Employee)
    RETURN e.name, b.division_name, coalesce(r.NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES,0) as messages
    ORDER BY messages DESC
    LIMIT 10',
{e:e}) YIELD value
return value
```

*Note: Remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j. See [this link](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).*

Comment: Hii Bruno, I tried this one. I am getting only 10 employees who have sent most number of messages in descending order.

Comment: @Ram, I updated the answer with a suggestion using APOC Procedures. Please, try it and tell me about the results. If the query not work as expected I will adjust it. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Bruno, I have installed the appropriate version of apoc plugin. I am using neo4j enterprise zipped version. I am getting the following error: `apoc.cypher.run is not available due to having restricted access rights, check configuration`.

Comment: @Ram, take a look in [this link](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-procedure-is-not-available-due-to-having-restricted-access-rights-check-configuration/) about the error.

Comment: @Ram I have updated a typo error in the query now. Please, tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Dear Bruno, Just as you said. I edited the conf file and It did work. But if a employee in finance division has sent messages to only 6 other employees then I need zero for other 4 entries (since i am trying to get top 10), also in descending order.

Comment: @Ram Of course! I have forgot the `OPTIONAL MATCH` and `DESC` modifier. Please, try it now. I have edited the answer another time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147793/discussion-between-ram-and-bruno-peres).